# Put $f(x) =\int_0^{t^2} \sin(x^4) dx$ and give a formula for $f'(t)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$f\left(t\right) = \int_{0}^{t^2} \sin\left(x^4\right)\ {\rm d}x$$

My answer:

The chain rule is
$$g'(t)f'(g(t))$$

So if
$$g(t) = t^2$$ and
$$f'(x) = \sin(x^4)$$

Then $f'(t)$ must be
$$f'(t) = 2t \sin(t^4)$$

Which was wrong. What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: Note that when $x = t^2$, $x^4 = t^8$.

Comment: $$f\left( t \right) =\int _{ 0 }^{ t^{ 2 } } \sin  \left( x^{ 4 } \right) { d }x\\ \frac { df }{ dt } =\sin { \left( { t }^{ 8 } \right)  } \cdot 2t$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following method:
$$ f(t)=\int_0^{t^2}\sin(x^4)dx$$
$$ f(t)=G(t^2)-G(0)$$
where $G$ represents the primitive of $\sin(x^4)$. Note that $\sin(x^4)|_{t^2}=\sin((t^2)^4)=\sin(t^8).$ Now,
$$ f'(t)=2tG'(t^2)=2t\sin(t^8).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Another method is to try to find a change of variables so that you can write
$$f(t) = \int_c^t g(x)\; dx$$
and then you have $f'(t) = g(t)$. The important thing is that you end up with "$t$" as the upper limit.